# spring boot application fails to start with the error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following repository

```
 @Repository
 public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, 
    Long> {
     }
```

and I tried to Autowire this repository as shown below in my Controller but I see this error

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;


    @GetMapping("/questions")
    public Page<Question> getQuestions(Pageable pageable) {
     return questionRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'questionController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'questionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kfz24.mockingservice.repository.QuestionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: And what is the package of QuesstionController, QuestionRepository and the thing you annotated with @SpringBootApplication ??\

Comment: did you add the annotation @EnableJpaRepositories in your config ?